# Unwanted vertical space between boxes (\offinterlineskip not working)

Tags: matrices, boxes, vertical-spacing

[image: Confusion Matrix]

I thought `\offinterlineskip` would remove the vertical spacing between the rows, but it does not seem to work. I want a small spacing before the last row only.

Does someone know what is going wrong here?

This is the code for the confusion matrix:

```
{
\offinterlineskip
\centering
\hspace*{0.9cm}\MyHBoxy{A}\MyHBoxy{B}\MyHBoxy{C}\MyHBoxy{D}\MyHBoxy{PA}\par
\MyTBoxy{A}{$N_{AA}$,$N_{AB}$,$N_{AC}$,$N_{AD}$}{$\dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{Ap}}$}
\MyTBoxy{B}{$N_{BA}$,$N_{BB}$,$N_{BC}$,$N_{BD}$}{$\dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{Bp}}$}
\MyTBoxy{C}{$N_{CA}$,$N_{CB}$,$N_{CC}$,$N_{CD}$}{$\dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{Cp}}$}
\MyTBoxy{D}{$N_{DA}$,$N_{DB}$,$N_{DC}$,$N_{DD}$}{$\dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{Dp}}$}
\vspace*{2.5px}
\MyTBoxy{UA}{$\dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{An}}$,$\dfrac{N_{BB}}{\sum_{Bn}}$,$\dfrac{N_{CC}}{\sum_{Cn}}$,$\dfrac{N_{DD}}{\sum_{Dn}}$}{-}
}
```

Boxes:

```
    \newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
    \parbox[c][.8cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
     }
    \newcommand\MyHBoxy[2][\dimexpr1.25cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
    \parbox[c][1.35cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
    }
    \newcommand\boxy[1]{%
    \fbox{\parbox[c][1.25cm][c]{1.25cm}{\centering #1}}%
    }
    \newcommand\MyTBoxy[3]{%
    \MyVBox{#1}
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{\boxy{##1}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}}
    \docsvlist{#2}
    \boxy{#3}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}
    }
```

Comment: Whatever is going wrong is hidden in code you are withholding. How are we supposed to know what you are doing with `\MyTBoxy`, `\MyHBoxy`? Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE? Where and how you define `\MyHBoxy` and `\MyHBoxy`?

Comment: Sorry about that! Completely forgot to add that part...I've added it now. Thanks in advance all!

Comment: If I run your code snippets in a standard `article` class while loading `amsmath` and `etoolbox`, the boxes _are_ attached to each other. So again: post a _complete_ code which reproduces the problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the tips and sorry for the bad explaination. I am new here indeed...I'll make sure my next question fully reproduces the problem. I've used your code @Zarko, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

As simple table with use `hhline` for horizontal and vertical rules in table, and `makecell for more vertical space in the last column's cells:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=3mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline, makecell}
\newcommand\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\mathbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{array}{r|*{4}{c|} |c|}
\mcbf{}     & \mcbf{A}  & \mcbf{B} & \mcbf{C} & \mcbf{D} & \mcbf{PA} \\
    \hhline{~|----||-|}
\mathbf{A}  & N_{AA}    & N_{AB}    & N_{AC}   & N_{AD}    & \dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{Ap}}\\
    \hhline{~|----||-|}
\mathbf{B}  & N_{BA}    & N_{BB}    & N_{BC}   & N_{BD}    & \dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{Bp}}\\
    \hhline{~|----||-|}
\mathbf{C}  & N_{CA}    & N_{CB}    & N_{CC}   & N_{CD}    & \dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{Cp}}\\
    \hhline{~|----||-|}
\mathbf{D}  & N_{DA}    & N_{DB}    & N_{DC}   & N_{DD}    & \dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{Dp}}\\
    \hhline{~:====::=:}
\mathbf{UA} & \dfrac{N_{AA}}{\sum_{An}}
                        & \dfrac{N_{BB}}{\sum_{Bn}}
                                    & \dfrac{N_{CC}}{\sum_{Cn}}
                                               & \dfrac{N_{DD}}{\sum_{Dn}}
                                                           & - \\
    \hhline{~|----||-|}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've used your code. Very helpful.

Comment: @jkool, than please accept my answer :-) (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer).